# "My..." Vs. "of mine"

Tags: formal-language, informal-language

Recently I noticed that there are people that instead of saying "My client" or "My friend" they say "a client of mine" or "a friend of mine". Initially, a couple of months ago I heard it from a German guy which is obviously not a native English speaker, and it wasn't natural to my ears, but today I heard it once from an [American English speaker](https://youtu.be/p1CxQ2Jx9LU?t=1358) too, and this brought me to the following question.

Assuming that the second way ('friend **of mine**') is correct, my question is if it's considered a formal or informal / slang? (especially in British English since I'm in touch with it more)

Comment: "Friend of mine" allows the phrase to be marked, when required, as indefinite by adding article "a". "My friend" is always definite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it (the "of mine" form) is particularly more or less formal. It may be slightly old-fashioned -- I see it a lot in novels from the first half of the 20th century, many of them British, but I also see and hear it frequently enough today. I have heard it enough (in mostly US English) and read it enough (in both UK and US sources) that I am confident it is natural, and I don't see that it violates any rules of grammar.